# Assert inequality for float in junit

Tags: java, junit

I´v just migrated to a newer version of JUnit where Assert.assertNotEquals has been removed so now i´m struggling to rewrite a test.

Original code:

```
Double givenLongitude = new Double(13);
assertNotEquals(givenLongitude, extract("position.longitude", eventDataJson, Float.class), 0.01d);
```

Where the extract method is a generic method that returns Float in this case.

My problem is that I would like to use Assert.assertFalse like this

```
Double givenLongitude = new Double(13);
assertFalse(givenLongitude.equals(extract("position.longitude", eventDataJson, Float.class)), 0.01d);
```

But since the assertFalse doesnt have a delta value i´m not sure how to accomplish this without losing the delta value in the comparison? Any suggestions?

Comment: why do you think the assertNotEquals doesn't exist any more. I've just checked the 4.11 source and it's still there

Comment: I´m using version 4.8.

Comment: Wow, you are correct. That's strange. 4.6 (I'm using) has it. 4.11 has it. Looks like they dropped it and then put it back in again in 4.11. You could try moving to that, it's in maven central.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move up to version 4.11. The assertNotEquals methods were reintroduced in this version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the prototype of extract method looks like the following:

`<T> T extract(String s, .... /*more parameters*/)`

In this case you can call it as following:

`<Float>extract("position.longitude", eventDataJson, Float.class)`

So, I guess you can do:

`<Float>extract("position.longitude", eventDataJson, Float.class).floatValue()`

If this is compiled you can use `assertEquals(float, float, float)`

Anyway you can always create special variable and assign value returned from `extract`:

```
float actual = extract(......);
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. So this means my test would become assertEquals(float,float,float) and it this passes i throw assert fail? That´s looks like a hack to me?